# What he said in this video (2:30-3:00)

Tags: meaning, listening

BBC Radio Liam Gallagher:

> Liam - Another thing that toss me annoying, when people go, comes out for a beer, no no no I am trying to be good and they say - just come for one. What is the point going for one. You know what I mean, they just try pull wool over your eyes. Who ever ask one? I am gonna get on, put clothes on, me and you in the boozer, alright "**not sure what he is saying here**"  you don't die?  Listen at that then we have the beer and that is it. We are going out. we gonna have a hundred. Do you know what I mean?

I am not sure about toss me annoying and the bold one I marked.
video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIgNHUMzKbA

Comment: First one sounds like "another thing that blows my nut" and the other sounds like "and how's it going off?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And another thing that does my nut in, is people who turn around and go "You coming out for a beer?" and you go, "no, no, no, I'm trying to be good." And they go "just come for one."  {shakes head} What is the point of going for one? Do you know what I mean? They're just trying to pull the wool over your eyes, aren't they? You know what I mean? Who ever has one? You know I'm going to get up, put my clothes on, meet you in the boozer, "All right man, how's it going?", "Ahh, f.. dog died". You've got to listen to that, then have the beer and that is it. {pause} If we're going out, we're going to go out and have a hundred, you know what I mean?

(I've tidied up some of the grammar and used standardised spelling, so althogh Liam says "nah" to mean "no" and "you got t'listen t' tha'" which becomes "you've got to listen to that")

So what you heard as "toss me annoying" is "does my nut in" (which means "makes me mad")

The part from "All right" is Liam describing a (typical?) pub conversation. "f.." is "fucking" but as this is for the radio, Liam avoids saying the word.

It's all a rant about people who ask you to come out for just one drink

Comment: You do not have to come from Manchester to use the word  "Nah!" as an emphatic negative. There is film of HM The Queen replying to a question with exactly that word. Watching it made my day.